# Adding validation before exporting PXGrid to excel

Tags: acumatica

I have a grid containing employee timecard information which will be exported to excel. I have to find a way to validate that all the employees have timecards approved for the period before allowing the export. Is there any way to manually trigger an excel export? I would then be able to create my own button and validate there.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 way to do this
1. U must validate the data first on the screen, before u export to xls.
Maybe u can create button process for validate the data, after validate is finish, on the screen just show the clean data what u want, after that u can export to XLS with existing button.
2. U can create button export. On Acumatica u can call the function export to file. I Have tried to generate to CSV. On the button export u can add logic, so when process export u can filter the data first.

Comment: The function export to file, is it PXRedirectToFileException?